# Copying CSV data into Postgres with Unix Timestamp values

Tags: postgresql

It is not really clear how to copy a CSV file that contains unix timestamp values into Postgres. For example, let's say that I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
timestamp, column_1, column_2, column_3
1439935260;"A";"B";"C"
1439935261;"A";"B";"C"
1439935262;"A";"B";"C"
```

I also have a database which has the following columns:

```
timestamp    | timestamp without time zone | 
column_1     | character varying(40)       | 
column_2     | timestamp without time zone | 
column_3     | timestamp without time zone |
```

I would expect the command

```
\copy my_table FROM 'my_file.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

to work, yet it doesn't. You would receive the error

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1439935260"

What is the proper way to copy CSV files with unix timestamp values into a table?

Comment: You can't copy that directly. You need to put it into a different table first, and the convert the "unix" value into a proper timestamp

Comment: if it's not much data - you can create trigger before insert on that table, whose function would do `NEW."timestamp" = to_timestamp(NEW."timestamp")` if the purpose of that table is to be always used for such `COPY` imports

Comment: @VaoTsun: the trigger hack is not possible, since in this case the query is cancelled prior to the BEFORE INSERT stage.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer on Database Administrators,

- [PostgresSQL date/time field out of range on seconds-since-epoch](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185878/2639)

I suggest

1. making the type on the table `abstime` if it's a new table.
2. then running the `ALTER` statement on the table when you're done to change the type.